# Show the position of an element in array JS

Tags: javascript

my question is the following: How can I get the position of an element of an array using **i**?

1. **I have to use only 2 functions.**
2. **The first function asks for the element, calls the second function and displays the position.**
3. **The second function looks for the element in the array and returns the position of that element.**

```
// Simple array with 5 elements. 

var x = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

first_function();  // The call for the first function 

function first_function(){
  const result = prompt("Search the word");
  document.write(i);
  second_function();
}

function second_function(x){
  let i = 0;
  while ( i < 5 ){
    if (x[i] == result){
    return i;
    i++
  }
}
```

Comment: You never pass a parameter to `second_function`

Comment: Also, the number of braces in your `second_function` are not balanced.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `Array.prototype.indexOf()`?

```
const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
letters.indexOf(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```js
document.write(second_function(i));
```

---

So, you want to ask the user what letter they want to get the index for?

1. Ask the user for their input.
2. **[Optional]** Transform the letter
3. Locate the index of the letter in the array.

```js
const letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

prompUserForIndex();

function prompUserForIndex() {
  let requestedLetter = prompt("Search the word").trim().toLowerCase();
  document.write(`Index: ${findIndex(letters, requestedLetter)}`);
}

function findIndex(letters, letter) {
  return letters.indexOf(letter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things wrong in your code. I have pointed those out in the code below.

```js
// Simple array with 5 elements. 

var x = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

function first_function() {
  const result = prompt("Search the word");

  // Once you get the result you should call the second function with the result as a parameter to get i
  const i = second_function(result);

  // second_function should return a value to store into i
  document.write(i); // i was not defined anywhere in your code earlier
}

function second_function(x){
  let i = 0;
  while ( i < 5 ){
    if (x[i] == result){
    return i;
    i++
  }
  return i
}

first_function();  // The call for the first function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Small changes to your code.

```js
var x = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

function first_function() {
  const result = prompt("Search the word");
  document.write(second_function(result));
}

function second_function(result) {
  let i = 0;
  while ( i < 5 ){
    if (x[i] === result){
    return i;
    }
    i++
  }
}


first_function();
```

Comment: The problem is that I cant use findIndex, that is one of the rules, I have to use like a loop or something

Comment: @Constantin, ah got it. just updated the answer